What is the origin of the "blink" spell for instant short-range teleportation?
The word "blink" is sometimes used as a name for instant short-range teleportation. Where did this usage originate?

Dark Matter (2015) had a "Blink Drive" which enabled their ships to instantly teleport long distances
Blink stalkers in Starcraft II (released 2010) could instantly teleport short distances
The spell "blink" in Dungeon Crawl: Stone Soup (confirmed in v0.11, 2012) and its predecessor Linley's Dungeon Crawl (confirmed to be in v3.11, 1999, but perhaps also the initial release in 1997, as the change log makes no mention of adding it). The base "blink" spell in this game is a short-range teleport to a random location, and a higher level version can be targeted to a location.

So, before comments and answers here, Linley's Dungeon Crawl was the first mention of "blink" in this way that I knew of.
There is also a spell named "blink" in Dungeons and Dragons. This spell has gone through many iterations, some of which involved teleportation and some of which did not. 1e (released 1977) had a spell named "blink" that involved short-range teleportation, 3e had a spell named "blink" that involved only transfer to and from the Ethereal Plane without changing the caster's position on their current plane, and 5e has a spell named "blink" that again involves short-range teleportation.
Are there any earlier examples? Later notable examples might also be interesting.

And don't forget Dishonored. The first in the series is a 2012 game, but features Blink quite heavily, as it is one of the basic powers of the protagonist/player.

D&D 5e's Blink does have a short-range teleport aspect: you return to an unoccupied space of your choice that you can see within 10 feet of the space you vanished from.  (https://www.5esrd.com/database/spell/blink/).  So you can use it to get through walls, for example, and to go an extra 10 feet beyond what you can normally do with move+dash during your turn if you're in initiative (where narratively you're maintaining 360 awareness of your surroundings, not just running as in a chase, where narratively it might slow you down.)

@PeterCordes Ah, true. The 3e version doesn't have that. https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/3e_SRD:Blink

@causative: Interesting.  5e was released in 2014, so for this question 3e is indeed the relevant version.  I see the 3e version did let you get through walls (some of the time), but with more fiddly mechanics that let you gamble on getting farther through a really thick barrier before you blink into a solid object and get shunted.  But it's still the PC doing the walking, not Blink itself changing your position as you blink, except when you would come back inside a solid object.

In the TV show I Dream of Jeannie (1965-1970) Jeannie blinks every time she performs a bit of magic.

1e AD&D Blink spell didn't make the enemy blink - it made the subject blink into another plane randomly, making them harder to hit.

@LAK No, that is 3e Blink (actually it goes back to 2e, I'll edit my post). 1e Blink is this: https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Blink_(cantrip)

@causative In the AD&D Player's Handbook, Blink is a 3rd-level magic-user spell whose description is with "..., the magic-user causes his or her material form to 'blink' out and back to this plane once again randomly during the duration".

@causative I do see that a web search turns out some other uses of the spell name, including the 'cantrips' added later in Dragon magazine and then the Unearthed Arcana book.  Weird that they re-used the spell name.

@LAK Are you saying you are looking at a paper 1st edition AD&D Players Handbook, published 1977-1983, and it says this? That would be in contradiction to forgottenrealms.

@causative Yes!  Though my copy is in a box in the basement, I'm looking at page 72 of a scanned pdf here: https://idiscepolidellamanticora.wordpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/tsr2010-players-handbook.pdf

@LAK OK, forgottenrealms is wrong then to omit non-cantrip "blink" from their 1e spell information. I'll edit again.

@Lexible You're right!

Blink is also a mage spell in World of Warcraft since 2004. "Teleports you forward 20 yds or until reaching an obstacle, and frees you from all stuns and bonds." (https://www.wowhead.com/spell=1953/blink)

@MarkRansom - Jeannie was my first thought as to the origin of the D&D blink spell's name. It certainly pre-dates D&D.

It dates from at least 1972; Zach Hughes used "blink drive" and "blinkstat" in The Book of Rack the Healer (1973, serialized in IF, July-August and September-October 1972).

I had to laugh when I filled in that official report. I've done it a hundred times and I've never had anything to write into the life questions other than a few facts about some weird bugs and some crazy plants. And this is a good indication of the fact that I'm not all wrong when I say that there's too much red tape in the program. How many hundreds of sheets of blinkstat paper have been wasted with those blank pages regarding life? How much does it cost to blink a stat from four hundred light-years away down to headquarters?


It's enough to give you the creeps, I'll admit. Twenty worlds killed. Up to 200 billions of beings done in. And our quaking isolationists think that every time we go out on a mission we're going to run head-on into the planet killers. You know my views on this. I think they did themselves in, because where the hell are they going to return from? We found nothing to indicate that they had developed anything half as sophisticated as the blink drive and the worlds they inhabited were packed together around five suns in the same neighborhood.


Note that this only covers physical transportation.  The use of "blink" to describe the arrival and departure of time travellers goes back much further, to at least "Adam Link in the Past", 1941, by Eando Binder.

Dungeons and Dragons had a monster called a "blink dog" as far back as the late 1970s (it appeared in the 1975 supplement Greyhawk pages 33 and 38).  The creature could make short-range teleports in combat, allowing it to appear close to an opponent and attack before the opponent could react -- an act referred to as "blinking".
Thanks to @DavidW for the reference check.


BLINK DOGS: Blink Dogs closely resemble African wild dogs, but they have high intelligence and the ability to employ a limited teleportation. They travel in packs, and when in combat they will teleport around their opponents) in a random fashion at random intervals (die 1-8 for direction, 5 out of 8 indicates the creature is teleporting. When reappearing they will come from 1' to 4' from their opponent(s), being able to attack in the same turn they teleported. This teleporting is known as "blinking." An inborn instinct prevents a blink into a solid object...


Ahh, this is probably where Linley's Dungeon Crawl got it from. Linley's Dungeon Crawl also has "blink frogs" which are probably taken from blink dogs.

I recall seeing an ad in Dragon Magazine for packs of miniatures, one of which was for 'wink dogs'.

@LAK That kind of thing was pretty common back in the day, when miniature makers didn't have a license to use a trademarked name.

@ZeissIkon I know - there are many other examples.  But 'blink frogs' reminded me of 'wink dogs'...

As stated, Blink Dogs appeared in OD&D Greyhawk (1975).  They were reprinted in the first edition Monster Manual (1977).  Then, in 1978, the 1e PHB introduced a player-facing spell called Blink: "By means of this spell, the magic-user causes his or her material form to "blink" out and back to this plane once again in random period and direction during the duration of each minute the spell is in effect. (Cf. ADVANCED DUNGEONS 8 DRAGONS, MONSTER MANUAL, Blink Dog.)"

I don't think this is about SF&F at all. I don't mean the question is off topic, it is most certainly on topic, but the answer isn't about SF&F but just about the English language. In English, and in many other languages, a blink is associated with something very fast. For instance, the expression in the blink of an eye to mean something that happened very quickly. Or blink and you'll miss it for something that is of very brief duration.
The word blink is also associated with disappearance. Something that disappears suddenly can be said to have blinked out of existence. I haven't managed to find a nice definition of this, but it is certainly used (and often used in sci-fi, actually, especially in stories that have stars disappearing). In any case, there are quite a few easy to find example of the phrase blink out of existence in printed works.
In other words, inventing a compound word involving blink is a very natural way for an English speaker to indicate something is supposed to be fast and involves something disappearing, as teleportation does. So I don't think any of the old usages mentioned in the other answers, great finds and interesting as they are, are actually relevant. It's just a natural result of the way that blink is used in the language.

Google ngram shows the term "blinked out of existence" had little usage prior to about 1990, and it rose exponentially from 1990 to 2018. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blinked+out+of+existence&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=0&case_insensitive=true Anyway, sure, a "blink" suggests something not lasting long, but someone had to first apply this term to specifically teleportation.

@causative sure, and if that's the question (who happened to use it first), fair enough. I read it as "who started the trend" and I suspect that various authors coined it themselves and weren't necessarily influenced by one another at all.

Well, it's an oddly specific use to have happened twice by accident. Lots of things don't last long; why teleportation specifically? Why not, I don't know, changing direction instantly, or cutting with a sword in an eyeblink, or setting off a flashbang grenade, or any other instant effect. Or indeed plane shift without teleportation, like 3e blink.

@causative precisely because teleportation combines speed and disappearance and I can't think of any other word than blink that carries both meanings. That's why I think it is just a natural choice. Based on nothing but my own speculation, of course, so I won't press the point.
